# Angularjs Datepicker: need to open calendar pop only on icon click, not on field focus

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working on Angular application. I have 2 Angular Datepickers on the page. Right now I am able to open the datepicker popup when i click the datepicker icon and when I focus the field  but my requirement is that datepicker popup should be available only when user clicks on calendar icon. I dont want datepicker popup opened on focus of datepicker field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about `angular-ui` directives, use the example in the official [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)

```
    <h4>Popup</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same code but somehow its opening the datepicker popup when I focus the date field. I dont know how to prevent it to open the popup on the focus.